# TinyMCE loads only on refresh in ReactJS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tinymce, reactjs, tinymce-rails

I'm rendering my submit form via ReactJS using tinymce-rails gem for Rails app. Followed this tutorial to install tinymce: https://github.com/spohlenz/tinymce-rails

Render code:

```
render: function() {
  <textarea
       ref="body"
       value={this.state.data.body}
       onChange={this.handleBodyChange}
       className="tinymce form-control"
       placeholder="Body"
       rows="10"
       cols="5"
       required
  />
}
```

The problem is that it renders only on page refresh, without it we have regular textarea. Turbolinks are disabled.
Tried to add `tinymce.init({selector:'textarea'})` to the `componentDidMount:`, but it's not working.

Comment: You mean that it's working when you initially load it, but then stops working on change? What's in `this.handleBodyChange`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29169158/react-html-editor-tinymce

Comment: @HannesJohansson when i access the page, it's not loaded. I need to refresh the page to ttrigger tinymce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I figured it out I cant do this, I have to add React mixin TinyMCE.